# Reading lines from a file and storing them in an array

Tags: c, file, io, fgets

I am having trouble reading text from a file line by line and storing each line into an array. I then need to print out the array that I get.

I'm not sure if I correctly allocated space for this array. And I'm getting a segmentation fault coming from the `fgets()` in my `read_one_line()` function.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

```
char* read_one_line(FILE* fp, char* line);
char* allocate_mem(FILE* fp, char* line);
```

```
void print_lines(char** lines, int num_lines){
    int i;
    for(i = 0 ; i < num_lines; ++i){
        printf("%d. %s", i+1, lines[i]);
    }
}
```

```
void free_lines(char** lines, int num_lines){
    int i;

    for(i = 0 ; i < num_lines; ++i){
        free(lines[i]);
    }

    if(lines != NULL && num_lines > 0){
        free(lines);
    }
}
```

```
FILE* validate_input(int argc, char* argv[]){

    FILE* fp = NULL;

    if(argc < 2){
        printf("Not enough arguments entered.\nEnding program.\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if(argc > 2){
        printf("Too many arguments entered.\nEnding program.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Unable to open file: %s\nEnding program.\n", argv[1]);
        exit(0);
    }
    return fp;
}
```

```
void read_lines(FILE* fp, char*** lines, int* num_lines) {
  *num_lines = 0;

  do {
    *num_lines += 1;
    *lines = malloc(*num_lines * sizeof(*lines));
    for(int i = 0; i < *num_lines; ++i) {
      *lines[i] = allocate_mem(fp, *lines[i]);
    }
    read_one_line(fp, *lines[*num_lines]);
  } while(read_one_line(fp, *lines[*num_lines]) != NULL);
}
```

```
char* read_one_line(FILE* fp, char* line) {
  fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp);
  return line;
}
```

```
char* allocate_mem(FILE* fp, char* line) {
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
  int length = ftell(fp);
  fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
  line = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
  return line;
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char** lines = NULL;
    int num_lines = 0;
    FILE* fp = validate_input(argc, argv);

    read_lines(fp, &lines, &num_lines);
    print_lines(lines, num_lines);
    free_lines(lines, num_lines);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: *seems like*. Find out for sure by using a debugger. It will give you that info instantly.

Comment: @kaylum I did use a debugger and that is where the segmentation fault occurred

Comment: Great. Please update your question to say so. It sounds a bit like you are uncertain :-)

Comment: Things seem out of order in `read_lines`. You should calculate `num_lines` before allocating memory. Or else use `realloc`.

Comment: Aside: As `ftell()` returns `long`, recommend `long length = ftell(fp);` and error checking.

Answer (score 1):

In the function `read_one_line`, `sizeof(line)` is not right, `line` is a pointer, you won't get the size of the container `line`, but the size of the pointer itself (likely 8 bytes), you'll need to pass the actual size of the container as a parameter of the function and use that in `fgets`.

Answer (score 0):

Um.

`lines[*num_lines]` is going to be one past the end of the array of lines you've allocated. You're instructing `fgets` to read into unallocated memory. Fix that in your `read_lines` function.

Answer (score 0):

it's done like that (prototiping)

```
FILE* f = fopen();
int result;
int n = 0;
int b = 0;
int bh = 0;

do
{
   int a;
   b++;
   fscanf(f,"%*[^\n]%n%*c" , &a);
   n = MAX(n,a);
} while (feof(f) == false);
n++;
char *x = calloc(n*b , sizeof(char));
rewind(f);
do
{
   fscanf(f,"%[^\n]%*c",&x[0][bh]);
   bh++;
} while (bh < b);
```

find and copypaste code of max . `#include sys/param.h` in linux and there's one in msvc also